# Alias a folder in localhost

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, alias

In `http://localhost` I have a folder named `_admin`

When I type `http://localhost/admin` practically I want to open `http://localhost/admin/_admin` but not with a redirect, I want with a htaccess alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a soft link.

```
ln -s _admin/ admin
```

So when you access `admin`, you will get contents of `_admin`

**OR**

You can use `mod_alias` module if you are using Apache web server.

> The Alias directive allows documents to be stored in the local
>   filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. URLs with a (%-decoded)
>   path beginning with URL-path will be mapped to local files beginning
>   with directory-path. The URL-path is case-sensitive, even on
>   case-insensitive file systems.

Example:

```
Alias /image /ftp/pub/image
<Directory /ftp/pub/image>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

For more reading, click on [me](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

Comment: You can add `Alias` in `server config or virtual host configs`

Answer (score 0):

With .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^something/_fakedir_/(.*) something/_originaldir_/$1
```